# Auth::routes() redirect loop

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

LoginController is in redirect loop back to login route.

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/register';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

}
```

routes/web.php :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Enums Route //

Route::get('/genderEnum', 'EnumController@gender');

Route::get('/modelTypeEnum', 'EnumController@modelType');

Route::get('/classCodeEnum', 'EnumController@classCode');

Route::get('/statusEnum', 'EnumController@status');

Route::get('/titleEnum', 'EnumController@title');

// test routes //

Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
```

RouteServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {

//        Route::middleware('web')
//             ->namespace($this->namespace)
//             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['auth', 'web', 'guest'],
            'namespace'  => $this->namespace
        ],function(){
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });

//        Route::group(array(
//            'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
//            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
//        ), function ($router) {
//            require base_path('routes/web.php');
//        });
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

I think the problem has to do with my RouteServiceProvider. I am trying to auth users and when I hit other auth routes I am redirected back to Login view and then it continues into 302 redirect loop to the login GET route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have your Auth routes using the 'auth' middleware. Try changing your service provider to:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web', 'guest'],
    'namespace'  => $this->namespace
],function(){
    require base_path('routes/web.php');
});
```

And routes/web.php to:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    // Enums Route //

    Route::get('/genderEnum', 'EnumController@gender');

    Route::get('/modelTypeEnum', 'EnumController@modelType');

    Route::get('/classCodeEnum', 'EnumController@classCode');

    Route::get('/statusEnum', 'EnumController@status');

    Route::get('/titleEnum', 'EnumController@title');

    // test routes //

    Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my User model because I created my own base model. In which I extended forcing me to implement Auth\Authenticatable and Auth\CanResetPassword to use auth::routes(). I had made a mistake with the way I had implemented some of the remember token functions and getAuthIdentifierName and getAuthIdentifier which caused the route issue. Also the reason I always got a null user when using Auth::user() method. However, after fixing that your answer lead me right into using my enums correctly and how I will use other controllers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my RouteServiceProvider back to this

RouteServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {

        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Mockery\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

use App\Model as Model;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'contact', 'username'
    ];

    /**
     * The column name of the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rememberTokenName = 'remember_token';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token', 'active'
    ];

    /**
     * the attributes that should be guarded from Mass Assignment
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at', 'password_hash'
    ];

    /**
     * Define table to be used with this model. It defaults and assumes table names will have an s added to the end.
     *for instance App\User table by default would be users
     */
    protected $table = "user";

    /**
     * We have a non incrementing primary key
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * relationships
     */
    public function contact(){
//        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class, 'id', 'contact_id');
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class);
    }

    /**
     * User constructor.
     * @param array $attributes
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
        parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
        // Your construct code.

        $this->active = 1;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @param $password string
     * set user password_hash
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPassword($password){
        // TODO Password Validation
        try{
            $this->isActive();
            $this->password_hash = Hash::make($password);
            $this->save();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Returns whether or not this use is active.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isActive(){
        if($this->active) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Throw new Exception('This user is not active. Therefore you cannot change the password', 409);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     *
     * getFullName
     * returns concatenated first and last name of user.
     */
    public function getFullName(){
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }


    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName(){
        return $this->getKeyName();

    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password_hash;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken(){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            return $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()};
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset(){

    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token){

    }

    public function validateAddress(){

    }


}
```